# Storing a variable in Oracle PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I hope you can help - I'm strying to assign a date to a variable, and then call that variable in my select query. The code I'm posting is only part of what I'm strying to do, I will be calling that variable more than once. 
I've tried to google for help, but I'm stuck on using the Select Into statement, as I've got so many selects already.

```
DECLARE 
    CurrMonth DATE := '27 may 2012'; -- Enter 27th of current month  

BEGIN

SELECT 
    a.policynumber
    ,a.cifnumber
    ,a.phid
    ,a.policystartdate
    ,b.sistartdate
    ,c.dateofbirth
    ,'28/02/2013' AS TaxYearEnd
    --Complete tax year end in the SELECT statement (once for tax year end and once for the age at tax year end)
    ,round ((months_between('28 feb 2013',c.dateofbirth)/12),8) AS AgeAtTaxYearEnd 
    ,b.sifrequency AS CurrSIFrequ
    ,b.sivalue AS CurrentSIValue
    ,b.simode AS CurrentSIMode
    ,d.anniversarydate AS CurrentAnnDate
    ,d.anniversaryvalue AS CurrentAnnValue
    ,b.ruleeffectivedate
    ,b.sistatus AS CurrentSIStatus
    ,b.paymentbranchcode AS CurrSIBranchCode
    ,b.transferaccounttype AS CurrSIAccountType
    ,b.transferaccountnumber AS CurrSIAccountNo
    ,SUM(k.unitbalance) AS unitbalance
    ,a.latestrule
FROM fcislob.policytbl a
    ,fcislob.policysitbl b
    ,fcislob.unitholderdetailtbl c
    ,fcislob.policyanniversaryvaluetbl d
    ,fcislob.unitholderfundtbl k
WHERE a.policynumber = b.policynumber
    AND a.policynumber = d.policynumber
    AND b.policynumber = d.policynumber
    AND a.phid = c.unitholderid
    AND a.phid = k.unitholderid
    AND c.unitholderid = k.unitholderid
    AND a.ruleeffectivedate = b.ruleeffectivedate
    AND a.ruleeffectivedate = d.ruleeffectivedate
    AND b.ruleeffectivedate = d.ruleeffectivedate
    AND a.latestrule <> 0
    AND c.authrejectstatus = 'A'        
    AND a.phid LIKE 'AGLA%'
    AND b.sistatus <> 'C'
    AND k.unitbalance >0     
    AND b.transactiontype = '64'
    AND b.sistartdate <= CurrMonth                                              
    AND b.sifrequency = 'M'

GROUP BY a.policynumber, a.cifnumber, a.phid, a.policystartdate, b.sistartdate , c.dateofbirth,b.sifrequency, b.sivalue, b.simode, d.anniversarydate, d.anniversaryvalue, b.ruleeffectivedate,
    b.sistatus, b.paymentbranchcode, b.transferaccounttype, b.transferaccountnumber, b.policynumber, a.latestrule;
    END;
```

Comment: Your "select into" is missing the "into"!

Comment: Yes, but where exactly do I put it? That is esentially my problem, I'm not sure of the syntax

Comment: `SELECT c1, c2, c3 INTO v1, v2, v3 FROM ...`

Comment: Do you actually want to use PL/SQL? If you're adapting, say, a script with multiple plain `select` statements that you run via SQL*Plus, that isn't neccessary - you can use `define` or bind variables. Not sure what your aim is.

Answer (score 3):

1. You have a `group by` clause so you need to group by all collumns which aren't aggregated.
2. Are you sure you have only one record in the result ?
3. As @TonyAndrews said, you need the into clause. You need to declare a variable for every collumn  and insert into it,

i.e.:

```
DECLARE
  v_policynumber fcislob.policytbl.policynumber%TYPE;
  v_cifnumber    fcislob.policytbl.cifnumber%TYPE;
  v_phid         fcislob.policytbl.phid%TYPE;
  -- and so on ...
  v_sum          number;
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(k.unitbalance), a.policynumber, a.cifnumber, a.phid -- and so on ...
      INTO v_sum, v_policynumber, v_cifnumber, v_phid -- and so on ...
      FROM fcislob.policytbl a -- and so on ...
  GROUP BY a.policynumber, a.cifnumber, a.phid -- and so on ...
END;
```

1. The way you deal with dates is not "healthy", IMO it's better to use `to_date` and not realy on NLS parameters

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, this helps a lot. I'm still very new SQL (maybe you could tell ;p ) but how would I use to_date?

Comment: Instead of `'27 may 2012';` use `to_date('27-05-2012','dd-mm-yyyy')'` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using PL/SQL to be able persist the date value between several plain `select` statements, then it will complicate things a lot - switching to `select into` isn't straightforward if you just want to display the results of the query, particularly if there are multiple rows.

Since you mention you have many selects, I'm guessing you have them in a script file (`example.sql`) and are running them through SQL*Plus, like `sqlplus user/password @example`. If so you can keep your plain SQL statements and use [positional parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIIEDF), [substitution variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIFHGB), or [bind variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#i1211850) to track the date.

First option is if you want to pass the date on the command line, like `sqlplus user/password @example 27-May-2012`:

```
set verify off
select 'Supplied date is ' || to_date('&1', 'DD-Mon-RRRR') from dual;
```

This uses the first positional parameter, which is referenced as `&1`, and converts it to a date as needed in the query. The passed date has to be in the format expected by the `to_date` function, which in this case I've made DD-Mon-RRRR. Note that you have to enclose the variable in single quotes, otherwise (unless it's a number) Oracle will try to interpret it as a column name rather than a value. (The `set verify off` suppresses messages SQL*Plus shows by default whenever a substitution variable is used).

You can reference `&1` as many times as you want in your script, but you may find it easer to redefine it with a meaningful name - particularly useful when you have multiple positional parameters - and then use that name in your queries.

```
define supplied_date = &1
select 'Supplied date is ' || to_date('&supplied_date', 'DD-Mon-RRRR') from dual;
```

If you don't want to pass the date from the command line, you can use a fixed value instead. I'm using a different default date format here, which allows me to use the date literal syntax or the `to_date` function.

```
define curr_date = '2012-05-31';
select 'Today is ' || date '&curr_date' from dual;
select 'Today is ' || to_date('&curr_date', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;
```

You may want to derive the date value, using the result of one query in a later one. You can use the [`column ... new_value`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm) SQL*Plus command to do that; this defines a substitution variable `curr_date` with the string value from the `today` column (alias) from any future query, and you can then use it in the same way:

```
column today new_value curr_date
select to_char(sysdate, 'DD-Mon-YYYY') as today from dual;
select 'Today is ' || to_date('&curr_date', 'DD-Mon-YYYY') from dual;
```

You can also use bind variables, which you define with the `var[iable]` command, and set with `exec`:

```
var curr_date varchar2(10);
exec :curr_date := '2012-05-31';
select 'Today is ' || to_date(:curr_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;
```

(`exec` is actually a wrapper around an anonymous PL/SQL block, so it means `begin :curr_date := '2012-05-31'; end;`, but you only really see that if there's an error). Note that it knows the bind variable is a string, so you *don't* enclose this in single quotes.

You can mix and match, so if you passed a date on the command line you could assign it to a bind variable with `exec :supplied_date := '&1'`; or to use current date `exec :curr_date := to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')`.

Many combinations possible, so you'll need to pick what suits what you're trying to do, and which you find simplest. Most, if not all, of these should work in SQL Developer too, but not sure about other clients.